# Flutter - Curved Navigation Bar - draw outside of the screen

Tags: flutter, uinavigationbar, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, animatedcontainer

I'm using curved_navigation_bar : [this one](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)

I have an animatedContainer that shrink to 1/4 of its size, and it has an Curved Navigation Bar,
when the Container shrinks the navigation bar draws a little bit outside of the container, I need a way to stop it.

attached: screenshot of the problem, you can see in a blue circle the extra drawing it does and that I need to stop.

[image]

I've searched the web for solution and even tried to examine the source code but with no luck

Comment: use `ClipRect` luke

Comment: what do you mean? use it outside the curvednavigationbar?

Comment: the docs say: *"A widget that clips its child using a rectangle.

By default, ClipRect prevents its child from painting outside its bounds, but the size and location of the clip rect can be customized using a custom clipper."*

Comment: it will work with the animation of the AnimatedContainer?

Comment: it did it worked with the animation, thank you this this the solution, you can write it in an answer so Ill accept it and you'll get the points you deserve or Ill write the answer so everyone will see.

Comment: good, write a self answer then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given by @pskink

using `clipRRect` ( or `clipReck` ) and inside of it put the entire child of the `AnimatedContainer`, will resolve this problem perfectly!